# using System.Web.Optimization can I mix css and .less files in the same bundle?

Tags: asp.net-optimization, dotless

It does not look like this is possible because LessTransform will be applied only once all the files have been merged and minified.

```
public class LessTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        response.Content = LessWeb.Parse(response.Content, (DotlessConfiguration) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dotless"));
        response.ContentType = "text/css";
    }
}
```

Is there a way to preprocess the less files in some way at Bundling time?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same needs and wrote a blog post about the solution that I finally came up with.  [Here](http://jareddev.com/post/2013/01/19/Using-less%7B%7D-%28dotless%29-with-MVC4-Web-Optimization)

This can be done relatively easy with a [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Less)/some web.config changes (detailed after the package installs so excluding here)/a new transformer in your bundling config.